# replace bits between i-th and j-th in N to M

Tags: java, algorithm

I am debugging some solutions for the problem, and here are details of the problem, my specific issue is, I think line 14 is wrong since we do not find sub-part of M (I mean bits between i-th and j-th), but using a whole M, correct?

You are given two 32-bit numbers, N and M, and two bit positions, i and j. Write a method to set all bits between i and j in N equal to M (e.g., M becomes a substring of N located at i and starting at j).
EXAMPLE:
Input: N = 10000000000, M = 10101, i = 2, j = 6
Output: N = 10001010100

```
public static int updateBits(int n, int m, int i, int j) {
  int max = ~0; /* All 1’s */

  // 1’s through position j, then 0’s
  int left = max - ((1 << j) - 1);

  // 1’s after position i
  int right = ((1 << i) - 1);

  // 1’s, with 0s between i and j
  int mask = left | right;

  // Clear i through j, then put m in there
  return (n & mask) | (m << i);  // Line 14.
}
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Once again I ask: please don't put line numbers in your code, especially if you're not going to indent it properly or reference any lines of code in your question.

Comment: @AndyTurner, thanks I will definitely take care next time. :P

Comment: so whats your question? If its to check the logic or not run your favorite IDE with print statements. or is your question for us to explain this method to you?

Comment: @MarquisBlount, sorry for confusions, my question is why we do not need to get sub-part (i-th to j-th bits) of M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of this problem should have added the following.

> The length of `M` will always equal the inclusive distance between `i`
>   and `j`. for example position `i` = 2 and `j` = 6 this means 5 spaces
>   are occupied; so the length of M will be 5. that means 5 bits in N will be substituted for M.

Alternatively think of it like this. i, and j only pertain to N each element in N between i and j will be replaced with M.

Comment: Thanks MarquisBlount, if M is not 5 bits (I mean for 32-bit integer, it does not have 27 heading zeros prefix), the original logic I posted is wrong, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct if M didnt have all leading 0's except the last 5 bits then this logic wouldn't behave correctly. This problem is from cracking the coding interview book. I think the question could have been explained better.

Comment: Thanks MarquisBlount, this is exactly I am confusing, thanks for answering and mark your answer as answered. Have a good day.